# How to find the most recent date time key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with datetime keys in isoformat. I need to find the most recent datetime key at or before a supplied datetime value. I have the following but it does not work and gives me a type error -

```
res = min([i for i in weather.keys() if i < takeoff], key=lambda x: abs(x - takeoff))
return weather[res]
```

This gives me the error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'". Can somebody please help me? I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: Check the data types.   Both should be a `datetime` dtype to perform the comparison.  The `datetime` library can be used to convert a string to a `datetime` object.  Then you’re golden.

Comment: If it's a dictionary, all the keys are probably strings. Even if they're strings of ISO format dates you'd need to convert them to actual dates before comparing them.

Comment: takeoff is a datetime. The keys in the dictionary are isoformat datetime keys. So I do need to convert them to datetime before comparison, I know, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `i` is a string, not a `datetime.datetime` object, but `takeoff` *is* such an object, so it can't be compared with a string.

Anyway, "datetime keys in isoformat" doesn't make much sense because `datetime.datetime` can't be "in ISO format" - they're just objects, without any format.

To solve this, convert each key of `weather` to a `datetime.datetime` object using [`date time.datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).